# Jenkins Jobs DSL - How to define a propertiesFile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to define a propertiesFile using Jenkins Job DSL Plugin.

Here is my line of code that is causing the ERROR: (script, line 108) No signature of method: 
    steps {
          propertiesFile("email_update.prop")
      }

javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.propertiesFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [email_update.prop]
Does anyone know the correct syntax to specify a propertiesFile in Jenkins  Job DSL?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on for what you need the propertiesFile for.

If you want to use a file from the workspace to add environment variables from it you need [environmentVariables context](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.toplevel.EnvironmentVariableContext.propertiesFile).
Or maybe you use it as a [file parameter](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.DownstreamTriggerContext.parameters-propertiesFile) to start a downstream job.

You only call `propertiesFile()` function when you have a file, that contains properties you want to use. If you want to create one during the build you can just create any file in a `shell` step with `touch mypropfile.properties` or whatever and write the props you need in it. Later you can use it in a downstream step.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be this from the [documentation](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.toplevel.EnvironmentVariableContext.propertiesFile)

```
job('example') {
    environmentVariables {
        propertiesFile('build.properties')
    }
}
```